# This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialzied. Make a Toast only on startup (Kotlin in Android Studio)

Tags: android, variables, kotlin

I want to make a toast message only ONCE when user enters given activity. I wrote this short piece of code but there is this syntax error 'This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialzied.'

```
   var pass = -1

    if (pass < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Profiles...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var pass += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `var` before the last `pass`:

```
var pass = -1

if (pass < 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Profiles...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    pass += 1
}
```